# Finding orthogonal complement of sequence of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials

Suppose you have a sequence of polynomials $\{ P_{k}, P_{k+1}, \dots \}$ where $P_j(z) = z^j + \mathcal{O}(z^{j-1})$ for $j \geq k$. I would like to construct an integral "test" that can identify if a polynomial $Q$ is in $\mathrm{span}\{ P_{k}, P_{k+1}, \dots \}$.

My initial thoughts is if you introduce an arbitrary inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and then check that $\langle Q, R \rangle = 0$ for all $R \in (\mathrm{span}\{ P_{k}, P_{k+1}, \dots \})^\perp$ which would show that $Q \in \overline{\mathrm{span}\{ P_{k}, P_{k+1}, \dots \}}$. The two difficulties I am having are these: how to construct $(\mathrm{span}\{ P_{k}, P_{k+1}, \dots \})^\perp$? (You might guess that the dimension of this orthogonal complement is $k$ but I suspect there are counterexamples to this.) And secondly, it is not at all clear to me that if $Q \in \overline{\mathrm{span}\{ P_{k}, P_{k+1}, \dots \}}$ and $Q$ is a polynomial then $Q \in \mathrm{span}\{ P_{k}, P_{k+1}, \dots \}$.

Comment: It feels like there are details missing from this question. You equip an arbitrary inner product to a space (presumably the space of complex polynomials, judging by the use of $z$), but you want an "integral test"? Does that mean that integration is involved? Can I infer from this that the arbitrary inner product must be one of the form $\int_a^b Q(x)\overline{R(x)} dx$? Or perhaps integration over some path in $\Bbb{C}$? Otherwise, I don't see how we could shoehorn integration into anything.

Comment: Also, inner products (particularly arbitrary ones) strike me as the wrong tool here. I suspect you're not going to do better than simply greedily subtracting multiples of $P_m$ from your polynomial, where $m$ ranges from the degree of your polynomial, down to $k$, and seeing if the result is $0$. It's the $z^0, \ldots, z^{k-1}$ terms that determine whether the polynomial lies in the span, and any test will depend heavily on the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: Yes the $z$ is misleading, I am thinking of polynomials on $\mathbb{R}$ and by an "integral test" I mean introduce a weight function $w$ with associated inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_w$ etc.